# Off-topic comments prevent voting/editing/closing/deleting

Tags: discussion, comments, locked-questions

> This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat.

Now, being locked, the question cannot be upvoted, downvoted, edited, closed, or deleted. Nor can I vote or flag comments. (In constrast, the answers to this question *can* be upvoted, downvoted, edited, or deleted, and their comments can be voted and flagged.)

It is strange that a large number of off-topic *comments* would freeze these question like this.

For instance, I would like to vote on [Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed temporarily to the "#LoveOverflows" logo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1) but I cannot vote because apparently someone else posted a lot of off-topic comments. It's nonsensical, and disappointing.

What is a better way of handling off-topic comments that would not be not so overly restrictive?

Comment: Yes, locking doesn't have any tuning options. Such is the nature of locks. Take into account that that post generates a lot of moderator work as it is, unlocking that post would increase the workload tremendously.

Comment: It *is* disappointing that there have been such a lot of off-topic comments. If only people could stick to the subject matter; should the logo be altered or not.

Answer (score 1):

The lock there was intended to prevent also commenting and blocks you only from voting, which you can still do, but on the top answer, as it supports the same point of view the question does. You can't answer also, but seems that any points of view are already expressed with existing answers (so vote on them), so I consider this to be a non-issue also.

Generally speaking, when a mod doesn't want to prevent commenting or any other actions on the question itself, they just move the conversation to the chat and the automatic comment is left on that post linking to the newly-created chatroom and saying that the comments are not for the extended discussions; example of such comment can be found [there](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/do-i-have-to-get-to-the-office-any-earlier-than-my-start-time#comment121506_48017):

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

with the "chat" linking to the appropriate room.